# How to delete blank page in mPdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am converting an html file to PDF by using `mPdf`, but the returned PDF file includes blank pages. I want to delete those blank pages.

Comment: What pages are blank? Does it add extra blank pages, or insert blank pages between pages randomly?

Comment: Thank you for reply. It add extra blank pages.

Comment: We'll need more information about the source. Can you add a link to your source html?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem and realized that my CSS was forcing these page breaks.  Make sure you don't have this in your CSS:

```
page-break-after: always;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be for many reasons:

1) Make sure the elements doesn't have unnecessary margins nor Paddings

2) Configure correctly the page properties (specially margins) :

```
$page_orientation = 0;
$page_size = 'Letter';
$page_margins = array('LEFT(int)','RIGHT(int)','UP(int)','BOTTOM(int)');
$pdf_output = 'I';
$css_files = array(
    'path/file.css',
    'path/file_2.css',
);

$orientationPage = array('','-L');

/* ===== [ MPDF ] =====*/
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', $page_size.$orientationPage[$page_orientation],'','',$page_margins[0],$page_margins[1],$page_margins[2],$page_margins[3]);

// Loading CSS

    for($i = 0; $i < count($css_files); $i++){
        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../../'.$css_files[$i]);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // 1 para indicar que es CSS

    }

// Set header & Footer (This are variables with html code)
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->SetTitle($title);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // <-- insert HTML

// Create PDF
    $mpdf->Output($titulo.'.pdf',$pdf_output);
```

3) Make sure you haven't unnecessary "Page Breaks" on the HTML

```
<pagebreak type="NEXT-ODD" resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="i" suppress="off" />
```

I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by removing the `AddPage` property from my code

I changed the following code

```
    // Code with bug
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(380,500));
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent);
    $mpdf->AddPage('P'); // It will add extra page - I that i removed this line
    $mpdf->Output();
```

Into this

```
    // code after resolving the bug
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(380,500));
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent);
    $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It's easy to leave an extra AddPage dangling on the end of a loop.  This was my problem as well.  If you're using CSS formatting for page breaks, addPage may be redundant.